Break when this exception type is thrown doesn't work in VS2022 when calling .NET API
When I upgraded to VS2022, I noticed that when exceptions are thrown the debugger often fails to show me the line that threw it. Instead it just displays:
Exception thrown: '<exception type>' in Unknown Module.

For example, when relativePath is null in this call:
string fileRelativePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(relativePath, fileName);

This occurs even if I select 'Break When Thrown' for every exception of every category in the Exception Settings window. I've also unchecked 'Enable Just My Code' in VS2022 options. I'm using .NET 4.7.1 and the Debug x64 configuration.
What am I missing?

Hi, could you please share the un-production code that can reproduce the issue? If you create a simple new console app, can you reproduce the issue again? And, what is the '' on your side, is it System.ArgumentNullException? If possible, please remove in-private information and share the related screenshot?

I'm not able to reproduce using a simple console app. It's a pretty frustrating problem, though. I can actually put a breakpoint on a line like this:
throw new Exception("hi");
and hit the breakpoint and single step and still get the generic "in unknown module" dialog.
